# Laravel Collection groupBy( ) not working with 2 values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller that gets all `opened` and `closed` projects.

```php
$projectsByRegister = collect($result)->groupBy(['date', 'closed']);
```

When this code is executed, it returns

[image]

---

With separated `groupBy` I can see that the values are correct:

```php
$projectsByRegister = collect($result)->groupBy(['closed']); // a flag 0 or 1
```

[image]

```php
$projectsByRegister = collect($result)->groupBy(['date']); // month / year
```

[image]

---

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
01/2018:
    0: [{...}]
    1: [{...}]
01/2019:
    0: [{...}]
    1: [{...}]

...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

$projectsByRegister = collect($result)->groupBy('date')->groupBy('closed');

Comment: Almost the same result as the first example in the question, but with a incrementing number where the `date` should be. And ignoring `groupBy('closed')`

Comment: Then use groupBy before collecting it.